# Tensor flow reshape usage

Tags: python, tensorflow

I saw in an example the following code :

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name='InputData') 
# image shape 28*28=784
XX = tf.reshape(X, [-1, 784]) 
# reshape input
```

What is the usage of tf.reshape here as we already have input data set coming from mnist data set and each image has a size of 784 (28*28).  So what are we gaining by reshaping the image again ?

Comment: Not sure where you saw this example, but it makes little sense indeed. The placeholder is already guaranteed to have size 784 in the last dimension so this use of reshape is not gonna do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If one component of shape is the special value -1, the size of that
>   dimension is computed so that the total size remains constant

In your example, 784 in both places may confuse you.

But if you want a 28 * 28 dimensions, you many need to reshape as shown below. Then the **-1** is inferred to **28**.

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name='InputData') 
XX = tf.reshape(X, [-1, 28])
```